# List in dataframe is different to the order it appears in the original list?

Tags: python, pandas

So lets say I have a list of lists:

data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0 , 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 4]]

When I am trying to output this into a dataframe, the dataframe is appearing as follows:

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Current (incorrect) output:

| list 1 | list 2 | list 3 | list 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

This is the output I am hoping for:

| list 1 | list 2 | list 3 | list 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Just transpose the dataframe: `df = df.T`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each sublist in `data` is supposed to become a row in `df`, not a column, so you have to transpose `data` and then turn it into a `df`, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data).T)
```

Alternatively, if `data` contains strings, you could do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(map(list, zip(*data))))
```

which transposes the list of lists and then turns into a `df`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to "push" the 0s to the end.

You can use `sorted` with a custom key.

The exact output you expect is yet ambiguous as the data is symmetric, but you can transpose if needed:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0 , 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 4]]

df = (pd.DataFrame([sorted(l, key=lambda x: x==0) for l in data])
        .T # remove the ".T" of you don't want to transpose
     )
```

*NB. If you want to push the 0s to the end **and** sort the other values, use `lambda x: (x==0, x)` as key*

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4  0
2  3  4  0  0
3  4  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think perhaps I was unclear in my original question. So my goal is to keep the 0s in the original order that they appear in the list as, rather than being pushed to the end.

So currently they are being pushed to the end, but rather I need them to retain their position as they appear in the list when converted to a dataframe

Comment: It doesn't make sense that this happens. Have you provided all details?

Comment: My apologies you're right, i forgot to include a detail in the question however it is now fixed, thank you for your help

Comment: It is still unclear. You cannot obtain the wrong output you describe from the provided input and command. The 4s cannot be on the second diagonal.

Comment: No sorry I mean I have fixed the problem now so i do not need further help. 
The question was unclear, I appreciate that and I apologise for this